# SDK SmartStore Soup Limit

Tags: limits, mobilesdk, salesforce-sdk-hybrid, smartstore, offline

For a proof of concept using Salesforce Mobile SDK, one major requirement is to be load 50k records from Salesforce and store locally offline.

After understanding the SmartStore function and underlying soups, it looks like the soups max out at 1000 record limit.

Is there a way to get around this maximum for records in soup?

-Hybrid app using Mobile SDK

Comment: We have been involved in many apps (iOS + Android) and several of the apps certainly have more than 1000 records in some of the soups. Perhaps you could share some info as to what you're seeing when you say these soups "max out"?

Comment: @SarahMcCandless can you provide more info please?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this today with the latest iOS SDK.  Salesforce has added a limit in the sample app SObjectDataManager class (which we often reuse):

static NSUInteger kMaxQueryPageSize = 1000;

At first glance this appeared to be for a page limit on the REST API but it is actually a query limit on the SmartSync as well.  You can either set it to a larger value or remove it entirely.